# Calling C# Assembly from SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I've found this articles (liks below) but method which is described in those articles doesn't work for DLL which was compiled with target framework 4.0!

Articles:
http://oassaf.wordpress.com/2007/05/24/calling-c-assembly-from-ssis-script-task/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SSIS_Call.aspx
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/michen/com-references-within-an-ssis-script-component)

Any ideas?

version: SSIS 2008 R2

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using?  I think each version uses a different .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest hosting your 4.0 component in IIS 7 or a custom windows service and exposing it via WCF.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of SSIS (2008) cannot use 4.0 framework.  It is limited to 3.5 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Josef: 4.0 doesn't work in SSIS 2008. Here is how you add a refernce to a 3.5 (or lower) dll:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html