# Do the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) have this kind of interaction with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to get some pictures from a folder and convert them to byte arrays with C# code, then insert the byte arrays into my table in the SQL Server database

Does this capability exist in SSIS?

If yes, what is the control of SSIS that can handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334465/calling-c-sharp-assembly-from-ssis-script-task , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253901/ssis-c-script-task-c-sharp-script-to-look-at-directory-and-store-the-name-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Script task control` in SSIS

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/adding-the-script-task-to-your-ssis-packages/

approach:

where you've iterate through folder using FOR each loop container and process it with script task where you can write C#.NET code.

Google for "Script task in ssis"  that might help you for more info.